# Change iFrame Source from separate iFrame with same parent?

Tags: javascript, html, button, iframe

Here's my full, latest code that doesn't work. Here's the main window HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Website</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
</head>

<body background="core_rec/web_res/cf2.jpg">
<center>
<table width="720" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>
<td width="180"><img src="core_rec/logos/metaltop.png" /></td>
<td colspan="3"><img src="core_rec/web_res/title.png" align="bottom"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="180"><img src="core_rec/logos/metalbottom.png" /></td>
<td width="70"><center><font id="menutext">Menu</font></center></td>
<td width="100"><center><font id="menutext">Info</font></center></td>
<td width="200"><center><font id="menutext">Products/Services</font></center></td>
<td width="170"><center><font id="menutext">Contact</font></center></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br /><br />
<table height="80%" width="720">
<tr>
<td width="140"><iframe src="iframes/menus/main.html" width="140" id="sidebar"></iframe></td>
<td width="540"><iframe src="iframes/bodies/main/main.html" width="540" name="bodyframe" id="bodyframe"></iframe></td>
</tr>
</table>
</center>
</html>
```

Here's the menus/main.html. It contains the button.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>iFrame Main</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/main.css" />
</script>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#000000">
<center>
<font id="sidebartext">
Main<br /><br />
Other Feeds<br /><br />
<button onclick="parent.document.getElementById('bodyframe').src='../bodies/main/othersites.html'">Other Sites</button><br /><br />
</font>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Whenever I push the button on the menu frame, the body frame doesn't change.

Comment: Post your full bloated code so I can fix..

Comment: Just try using top.document.getElementById() once and if it sdoesn't work, top.window.document.getElementById()

Comment: If you have chrome just be sure to check the javascript console for errors due to security reasons. Its very stringent. Many things are not allowed with file:// protocol, so try the same on server once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to run this on a simple server and test. Many browsers have restrictions when it comes to iframes.

Many files don't work properly if using file:// protocol, which will be used if you directly open the html file (i.e.: Not through a server).

Comment: ah. lemme throw it up on my server and check it.

Comment: Good to know. NEw browsers have many unexpected security features which block a lot activities, so be in the lookout if something goes wrong.

Comment: Yeah thanks. Now I know to first upload something if it isn't working, before getting too frustrated over it.

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled `getElementById`: last letter `d` should not be uppercase.

Instead of `window.document.getElementById` you could write `document.getElementById`, because `window` is the global object in browser javascript (at least, global per window/(i)frame)

http://jsfiddle.net/kNrVL/

Comment: Wow. I must've been tired last night. I look at that code and have no idea why I wrote window. I edited my post with better code, which is what I mean in the first place. From which perspective do I set the source path? From the target iframe, from the parent window, or from the iFrame the button's on?